# External DNS server (centos named) inconsistently resolving user queries

Tags: domain-name-system, centos7, bind

I have a cluster of DNS servers which sit behind a public IP.

These servers resolve some of the time but other times they just return a ServFail error code for any queries

The setup I have is not typical (this was inherited).

Basically on the server there is a namespace called gi, here is where named service is been used by a new service call srv-gi
'''

```
#!/bin/sh

start_service() {
        ip netns exec gi /usr/sbin/zebra -d -A 127.0.0.1 -f /etc/quagga/zebra.conf
        ip netns exec gi /usr/sbin/bgpd -d -A 127.0.0.1 -f /etc/quagga/bgpd.conf 
        #DNS service
        ip netns exec gi  /usr/sbin/named -u named -c /etc/gi-named.conf
}

start_service
```

'''

The named.conf file has also been renamed to gi-named.conf file.

//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//
// See the BIND Administrator's Reference Manual (ARM) for details about the
// configuration located in /usr/share/doc/bind-{version}/Bv9ARM.html

```
options {
        listen-on port 53 { Public IP; };
        #listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        allow-query     { any; };
        allow-query-on  { PublicIP; };

        /*
         - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
         - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable
           recursion.
         - If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access
           control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
           cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification
           attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
           reduce such attack surface
        */
        recursion yes;
        allow-query-cache { Internal Range; };
        allow-query-cache-on  { PublicIP; };



        query-source address Public IP ;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};


logging
{
/*      If you want to enable debugging, eg. using the 'rndc trace' command,
 *      named will try to write the 'named.run' file in the $directory (/var/named).
 *      By default, SELinux policy does not allow named to modify the /var/named directory,
 *      so put the default debug log file in data/ :
 */
        /*channel default_debug {
                print-time yes;
                print-category yes;
                print-severity yes;
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };*/
        channel queries_log {
                file "/var/log/queries" versions 1 size 20m;
                print-time yes;
                print-category yes;
                print-severity yes;
                severity debug 3;
        };

        category queries { queries_log; };
        category client { queries_log;  };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

Also to note i have a quagga riuter configured to allow DNS resolution via Public IP

```
/etc/quagga/bgpd.conf

!
! Zebra configuration saved from vty
!   2019/10/11 10:11:45
!
!
router bgp AS
 bgp router-id PublicIP
 network PublicIP/32
 network CoreIP/32
 neighbor DUB1-WGW peer-group
 neighbor DUB1-WGW remote-as AS
 neighbor DUB1-WGW soft-reconfiguration inbound
 neighbor DUB1-WGW route-map XXXXX out
 neighbor CoreBGPIP peer-group DUB1-WGW
 neighbor CoreBGPIP peer-group DUB1-WGW
!
ip prefix-list XXXX seq 5 permit PublicIP/32
ip prefix-list XXXX seq 10 permit PrivateIP/32
!
route-map DNS_TO_GI permit 10
 match ip address prefix-list XXXXX
!
line vty
!

/etc/quagga/zebra.conf

!
! Zebra configuration saved from vty
!   2019/10/11 10:11:45
!
hostname hostname
!
interface ens160
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
!
interface ens192
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
!
interface ens192.890
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
!
interface ens192.892
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
!
interface XX
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
!
interface lo
!
ip prefix-list XX seq 5 permit PublicIP3/32
ip prefix-list XX seq 10 permit PrivateIP/32
!
route-map XXXX permit 10
 match ip address prefix-list XXX
!
!
!
line vty
!

# show ip route
Codes: K - kernel route, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP,
       O - OSPF, I - IS-IS, B - BGP, A - Babel,
       > - selected route, * - FIB route

B>* 0.0.0.0/0 [20/10] via neighbor IP, ens192.892, 00:02:18
C>* 127.0.0.0/8 is directly connected, lo
C>* Public IP/32 is directly connected, lo
C>* NeighborSubnet/30 is directly connected, ens192.890
C>* NeighborIP/30 is directly connected, ens192.892
C>* LocalIP/32 is directly connected, lo
```

I am testing resolution using a test APN and while I can get resolution one one APN as sson as I introduce a second APN i just encounter the following errors below from a tcpdump:

```
11:29:38.065284 IP PublicIP.domain > internal IP.p2pcommunity: 30622 ServFail 0/0/0 (44)
11:29:38.265736 IP PublicIP.domain > internal IP.32209: 12606 ServFail 0/0/0 (37)
11:29:38.266037 IP PublicIP.domain > internal IP.10793: 26678 ServFail 0/0/0 (37)
11:29:38.295727 IP PublicIP.domain > internal IP.ibm_wrless_lan: 23483 ServFail 0/0/0 (33)
11:29:38.296038 IP PublicIP.domain > internal IP.22097: 8347 ServFail 0/0/0 (33)
11:29:38.297532 IP PublicIP.domain > internal IP.31026: 23400 ServFail 0/0/0 (38)
11:29:38.298117 IP PublicIP.domain > internal IP.23707: 26481 ServFail 0/0/0 (38)
```

and from /var/log/queries

```
22-Sep-2020 11:31:07.552 client: debug 3: client InternalIP#61793 (www.facebook.com): error
22-Sep-2020 11:31:07.552 client: debug 3: client InternalIP#61793 (www.facebook.com): send
22-Sep-2020 11:31:07.552 client: debug 3: client InternalIP#61793 (www.facebook.com): sendto
22-Sep-2020 11:31:07.552 client: debug 3: client InternalIP#48008 (2.android.pool.ntp.org): error
22-Sep-2020 11:31:07.552 client: debug 3: client InternalIP#61793 (www.facebook.com): senddone
22-Sep-2020 11:31:07.552 client: debug 3: client InternalIP#61793 (www.facebook.com): next
22-Sep-2020 11:31:07.552 client: debug 3: client InternalIP#61793 (www.facebook.com): endrequest
22-Sep-2020 11:31:07.553 client: debug 3: client InternalIP#48008 (2.android.pool.ntp.org): send
22-Sep-2020 11:31:07.553 client: debug 3: client InternalIP#48008 (2.android.pool.ntp.org): sendto
22-Sep-2020 11:31:07.553 client: debug 3: client InternalIP#48008 (2.android.pool.ntp.org): senddone
22-Sep-2020 11:31:07.553 client: debug 3: client InternalIP#48008 (2.android.pool.ntp.org): next
22-Sep-2020 11:31:07.553 client: debug 3: client InternalIP#48008 (2.android.pool.ntp.org): endrequest
```

I am really unsure of how to resolve this issue, any pointers ort advice would be greatly appreciated

Outputs of dig command

```
dig facebook.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-74.el7_6.1 <<>> facebook.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 7204
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;facebook.com.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
facebook.com.       93  IN  A   31.13.86.36

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: internal DNS#53(Internal DNS)
;; WHEN: Tue Sep 22 19:38:58 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 57


dig @PublicIP facebook.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-74.el7_6.1 <<>> @PublicIP facebook.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

dig @208.67.222.222 facebook.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-74.el7_6.1 <<>> @208.67.222.222 facebook.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

ip netns exec gi tcpdump -n -f 'port 53' -i any
09:55:35.676645 IP PublicIP.domain > InternalIP.46571: 36451 ServFail 0/0/0 (32)
09:55:35.676939 IP PublicIP.domain > InternalIP.37817: 52592 ServFail 0/0/0 (32)
09:55:35.677865 IP PublicIP.domain > InternalIP41737: 52624 ServFail 0/0/0 (32)
09:55:35.713870 IP PublicIP.34042 > 193.0.14.129.domain: 11264 [1au] A? mtalk.google.com. (45)
09:55:35.713914 IP PublicIP.11218 > 193.0.14.129.domain: 3623 [1au] NS? . (28)
09:55:35.768649 IP 193.0.14.129.domain > PublicIP.11218: 3623*-| 0/0/1 (28)
09:55:35.784456 IP 193.0.14.129.domain > PublicIP.34042: 11264-| 0/0/1 (45)
09:55:36.045130 IP PublicIP.wcbackup > 192.112.36.4.domain: 28368 A? update.googleapis.com. (39)
09:55:36.063323 IP InternalIP.49382 > PublicIP.domain: 57145+ A? accounts.google.com. (37)
09:55:36.064459 IP PublicIP.48169 > 193.0.14.129.domain: 15825 [1au] A? accounts.google.com. (48)
09:55:36.065883 IP APNIP.54312 > PublicIP.domain: 53585+ A? accounts.google.com. (37)
09:55:36.080202 IP 192.112.36.4.domain > PublicIP.wcbackup: 28368- 0/13/14 (499)
09:55:36.120905 IP 193.0.14.129.domain > PublicIP.48169: 15825- 0/15/27 (1182)
09:55:36.170289 IP InternalIP.59759 > PublicIP.domain: 52061+ A? www.google.com. (32)
09:55:36.224316 IP PublicIP.5346 > 192.112.36.4.domain: 40438 A? www.facebook.com. (34)
09:55:36.257993 IP 192.112.36.4.domain > PublicIP.5346: 40438- 0/13/14 (494)
09:55:36.441576 IP PublicIP.domain > InternalIP.65408: 45517 ServFail 0/0/0 (39)
09:55:36.441666 IP PublicIP.domain > InternalIP.60664: 54663 ServFail 0/0/0 (39)
09:55:36.442994 IP PublicIP.domain > InternalIP.48634: 56799 ServFail 0/0/0 (39)
09:55:36.443474 IP PublicIP.domain > InternalIP.36045: 34980 ServFail 0/0/0 (39)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i believe I go to the bottomof this issue.

Basically this error came from my misunderstanding of both linux and bind service.

A previous colleague built out these DNS servers and created a service which piggybacked the named service /usr/local/bin/service-gi

```
#!/bin/sh

start_service() {
        ip netns exec gi /usr/sbin/zebra -d -A 127.0.0.1 -f /etc/quagga/zebra.conf
        ip netns exec gi /usr/sbin/bgpd -d -A 127.0.0.1 -f /etc/quagga/bgpd.conf
        ip netns exec gi  /usr/sbin/named -4 -u named -c /etc/gi-named.conf
}

start_service
```

This service essentially runs the named service with my quagga virtual router and it was working as a forwarder (i had to change the config so it is now a recursive server).

However the mistake I made was starting and running the named service and running this in parallel with the custom service(I did this for monitoring purposes as the tool we used would only recognise the generic named service and not the custom service) but because the 2 services were working at the same time the queries could not be resolved.

Once the named service was stopped and i solely used the custom service the queries began to resolve successfully